# Combined KE for an object rotating about a point other than COM

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I know the KE equation for combined translational and rotational motion, which is $K=Mv^2/2+I\omega^2/2$, and here $v$ is the velocity of COM and $I$ is the moment of inertia about the COM. But what if the body rotates about a point $\mathcal{P}$ other than the COM? Can I use the the velocity of $\mathcal{P}$ and moment of inertia about $\mathcal{P}$ in the equation?

Comment: Use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to determine the value for $I$ about $P$.

Comment: Yes but can I use the same equation with respect to P rather than using it wrt COM? Because my book has only mentioned the formula wrt com